# How do I recover the password to a gmail account with hydra?

Tags: security, passwords, gmail, password-recovery, brute-force

```
hydra -S -l "$email" -P w_file -V -s 465 smtp.gmail.com smtp
```

Where `email` is just one one my gmail accounts and `w_file` is a file with three incorrect passwords and one correct (`karina6c` in the last line is the correct password. Hydra fails to recover the password, I get the following output:

```
Hydra v9.2 (c) 2021 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - Please do not use in military or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes (this is non-binding, these *** ignore laws and ethics anyway).

Hydra (https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra) starting at 2024-01-04 12:33:21
[INFO] several providers have implemented cracking protection, check with a small wordlist first - and stay legal!
[WARNING] Google Mail and others have bruteforce and hydra detection and send false positives. You are not doing anything illegal right?!
[WARNING] !read the above!
[DATA] max 4 tasks per 1 server, overall 4 tasks, 4 login tries (l:1/p:4), ~1 try per task
[DATA] attacking smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465/
[ATTEMPT] target smtp.gmail.com - login "*******@gmail.com" - pass "jdut" - 1 of 4 [child 0] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target smtp.gmail.com - login "*******@gmail.com" - pass "kdfsknf" - 2 of 4 [child 1] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target smtp.gmail.com - login "*******@gmail.com" - pass "krege" - 3 of 4 [child 2] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target smtp.gmail.com - login "*******@gmail.com" - pass "karina6c" - 4 of 4 [child 3] (0/0)
1 of 1 target completed, 0 valid password found
Hydra (https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra) finished at 2024-01-04 12:33:27
```

Does my script fail because of the access to third-part apps and device [no longer being an option](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) with gmail? Or is there an error with my script?

Comment: https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/issues/613

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-answer that is actually the correct answer:

*You don't.*

This is because brute-force password guessing as a method for account recovery - *even for your own account* - is against the terms and conditions of most major email providers.

Your only permitted recourse to account recovery is to go through support channels.